# Create Permanent Redirect for old URL does not seem to work

Tags: url-rewrite

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

I have the "Create Permanent Redirect for old URL" checked but Google found 922 Site not found Crawl Errors (they come up with "404
You might want to check that URL again or head over to our homepage." message on the site when you go to that URL).

We did change the category structure recently and I re-indexed after that.

When I go to CATALOG - URL REWRITE Management - it shows **322505** records. **(I edited this a few days later and it now has a Total 330684 records found an increase of 8000+ records in 2 days - why is that? What does this mean? And what do I need to do with it?)**

What does this mean and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You should go through this link of Magento to get details about Index management http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/index-management.html

Comment: Envision Ecommerce: Sorry I made a mistake in my post - what I meant to write is.....When I go to CATALOG - URL REWRITE Management - it shows 322505 records. I have been re-indexing correctly. Thanks.